# Could not find the main class: when running Java Jar?

Tags: java, linux, jar

I'm having trouble running a java Jar file. I'm getting the error "Could not find the main class: com.body.Mouth. Program will exit."

```
Valid (No error):
running Mouth class from eclipse. main function is in Mouth.


Invalid (could not find main class error):

    java -jar Eat.jar
    java -jar Eat.jar com.body.Mouth
```

thanks,

Hank

Comment: Check the following SO post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149463/jar-file-could-not-find-main-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
java -classpath PATH_TO_EAT.jar com.body.Mouth
```

Comment: so it would be java -com.body.Mouth PATH_TO_EAT.jar com.body.Mouth?

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
java -jar Eat.jar
```

Will attempt to execute the Main Class found in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` that would look something like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Created-By: 1.7.0_06 (Oracle Corporation)
Main-Class: com.body.Mouth
```

You can learn more about creating an executing JAR [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)